# Fodder - idiomatic meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/little-sign-progress-obama-putin-speak-231431925--politics.html

> While U.S. officials denied those accusations, confirmation of Brennan's visit could provide **fodder** for Russian officials to create a pretext for further incursions into eastern Ukraine.

What are the authors trying to suggest and what does in this context the word **fodder** mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fodder](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fodder&searchmode=none) is food for animals.

In an idiomatic way, it is used in much the same way here as in the expression *food for thought*.

The allegations could provide Russian officials with material to create a pretext.

The word *fodder* usually comes with negative connotations. Although it provides something for them to create that context, it will not provide any real argument with a strong base. They can just "gobble it up" in order to create (new) propaganda.

The implication is that Russian officials will use any *excuse* to suit their needs, even if it does not create a very strong basis for their actions.

Another way *fodder* is (was?) used was in the expression [cannon fodder](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=canon+fodder), to describe soldiers that served as "food for the enemy cannons" - that is, their role on the battle field would consist mostly of being shot to piece by enemy fire.

Answer (score 2):

[*Fodder*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fodder) is *raw material* which can be used to build something. It is not particularly idiomatic when used in this way.

> While U.S. officials denied those accusations, confirmation of Brennan's visit could **provide fodder** for Russian officials to create a pretext for further incursions into eastern Ukraine.

In this context, it means that the Russian officials might see the confirmation of Brennan's visit as a reason to react in a particular manner, to be given the raw materials with which to build a case for something, so to speak.

Comment: 'Not particularly idiomatic'. This is a very telling point. Is a dead metaphor no longer a metaphor? I'm not sure I've seen anyone commit to print (before now!) on this issue. Certainly, when dictionaries begin to add definitions of (once?) metaphorical senses for words, without adding a 'metaphorical' tag, one begins to wonder....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - if *fodder* means *raw materials* as opposed to *lowish quality food for animals*, then is it a metaphor/idiom (dead or alive)? Perhaps it is only understood as *food*?

Comment: ... Grammar Monster has: 'The term _literal meaning_ denotes that all words are in strict accordance with their _original_ meanings. In other words, to apply the literal meaning is to take the words in their most basic sense without metaphor or exaggeration.' But also on the internet: '... the literal meaning of a word, the 'dictionary definition.' ' [emphasis mine]. Which dictionary definition? Which dictionary? [sounds like a quote from Churchill :-)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Hmm. One must build an argument out of something. What are the *raw materials* of an argument? Is that itself a metaphor? I can see *fodder* for *fuel* for an argument as a metaphor. Maybe it really is very telling. I have no objection to it being seen as an idiom or metaphor.

Comment: @ medicacomment1: The first-mentioned sense in these dictionaries (your link) is the 'animal feed' one; they list polysemes in their researched order of frequency of recent use. I'm sure OED will also put this sense first, but for the reason that it was the original one. I'd like some grammar czar to decide on whether inclusion of a broadened sense in a dictionary (without any tag) removes its former 'metaphorical' status. (Then we can lock the czar up again before they do some damage.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - ok, I know I'm very dense, but are you saying that *raw material* is itself a metaphorical definition of *fodder*? If you are, I'm sorry I was so slow on the uptake (!). Now I see (I think) what you mean. And I would need to agree that it *is* telling of where metaphors go to die. Very good points, all. Gosh, I hate it when I am so dense.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining myself too well. Originally, 'fodder' meant feed for livestock, period. [see especially the Collins etymology] Then metaphorical extensions were used more and more commonly. So much so that now, most dictionaries list these secondary definitions as separate senses. Does this mean they should no longer be termed 'metaphorical' usages, as these denotations are given without a 'metaphorical/figurative' tag? It depends on what one's exact definition of 'metaphor' is, and I've seen conflicting opinions. So I liked your sensibly hedged 'It is not particularly idiomatic'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thank you for your patience. This is quite interesting, and I have not really given it much thought until now.

Comment: The best intro (100+ pages !) to idioms and related devices I've come across is 'Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English ...' by Rosamund Moon. I'm not sure if it's available online. There's [I've used plural there's!] a lot of excellent analysis (eg _transparency; invariance_), classifications (eg _are all proverbs idioms?_), and examples, but also a necessary section looking at the academic bunfight over what the terms 'idiom' and 'idiomatic' should actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in a figurative sense meaning an *excuse*; using the word *fodder, food for animals* he is hinting at the fact that the visit could nourish, create a pretext for further incursions.

Comment: +1 for nourish, fuel would do just as well in all aspects of the word 'fodder'.

Answer (score 0):

The word originally means "food for animals", and used in this context it means something like  "raw material", with the implication of low quality. Usually, when you see the word used in examples like "Her behavior provided regular fodder for gossip around town", it means that her behavior was the raw material for the gossip.

In this context, what the article is trying to convey is that while the American's claim that the thing that happened doesn't mean anything, the Russians are still going to use it as an argument for further action. In other words, the Russians need arguments on their side, so they use whatever they can find, regardless of whether it has any merit or not.

Answer (score 0):

5526  GK5963  chortazesthai = to be foddered  V-PPN.5745

5528  GK5965  chorton = to~a~hay  N-ASM.04

The Greek noun "chorton" means "hay," so the associated word family verb might literally be "to hay;" however, this is more clearly conveyed as "to fodder"

Paul uses this verb in Philippians 4:12...

"and, I have had perceived to be humbled, and I have had perceived to abound; in with~every [one], and among with~all [ones] I have had been initiated, even to be foddered and to hunger, even to abound and to be shorted;"

Οἶδα καὶ ταπεινοῦσθαι, οἶδα καὶ περισσεύειν· ἐν παντὶ καὶ ἐν πᾶσιν μεμύημαι καὶ χορτάζεσθαι καὶ πεινᾷν, καὶ περισσεύειν καὶ ὑστερεῖσθαι.